# Duvidas com REACTJS CreateContext

Tags: react, typescript

main.tsx:

```
   import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { Home } from './pages/home'
import { AppContextProvider } from './pages/home/context/TextContext'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Home />
    </AppContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

index.tsx

```
import { useTextContext } from "./context/TextContext"


export function Home(){
    const context = useTextContext()
    console.log(context)
    return(
        <>
            <p>{context.text}</p>
            <button onClick={(e) => context.setText('blablabla')} type="button">Teste</button>

        </>
    )
}
```

textcontext.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";

interface INITIAL_STATE {
    text: string,
    setText: (text: string) => void

}

interface STATE_TEXT {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

export const AppText = createContext({} as INITIAL_STATE)



export const AppContextProvider = (props: STATE_TEXT) => {
    const [textHandle, setTextHandle] = useState<string>('Inicio')

    const addHandleText = useCallback((text: string) => {
        setTextHandle(text)
    }, [textHandle])

    return(
        <AppText.Provider value={{text: textHandle, setText: addHandleText}}>
            {props.children}
        </AppText.Provider>
    )
}

export const useTextContext = () => {
    const context = useContext<INITIAL_STATE>(AppText)
    return context
}
```

Na hora de puxar os dados no home vem um dicionário vazio, mesmo passando o text e a função que está no usestate, queria entender o porquê, pode ser um erro leigo, mas to quebrando a cabeça

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Problemas usando React Context](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476140/problemas-usando-react-context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fez errado nesse trecho de código: `{{text: textHandle, setText: addHandleText}}` onde deveria passar a variavel e a função de mudança de estado logo `{{text, setText}}` conforme criado na parte do `Context`. Você está confundido tipo criado na `interface` com o valor que é passado para o contexto controlar.

Tem um exemplo bem básico e didático onde três componentes compartilham do mesmo estado, observe:

```js
const AppTextContext = React.createContext();

const AppTextProvider = (props) => {
    const [text, setText] = React.useState('Inicio')
    return(
        <AppTextContext.Provider value={{text, setText}}>
            {props.children}
        </AppTextContext.Provider>
    );
}
function useText() {
  const {text, setText} = React.useContext(AppTextContext);
  return {text, setText};
}

function App() {
  const {text} = useText();
  return (
    <div>{text}</div>
  );
}

function Label() {
  const {text} = useText();
  return (
    <div>{text}</div>
  );

}

function Input() {
  const {text, setText} = useText();
  return (
    <div><input type="text" value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} /></div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <AppTextProvider>
    <App/>
    <Label/>
    <Input/>
  </AppTextProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Outros exemplos:

- [Problemas usando React Context](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476140/problemas-usando-react-context/476150#476150)
- [Como pegar o valor de um input e usar em outro componente em react?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/547030/como-pegar-o-valor-de-um-input-e-usar-em-outro-componente-em-react/547053#547053)
- [Passar função pra outro componente - ReactJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/566911/passar-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pra-outro-componente-reactjs/567179#567179)
- [Passar estado entre componentes sem hierarquia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/463035/passar-estado-entre-componentes-sem-hierarquia/463324#463324)